# Keep getting build fail when scaffold-DbContext for a remote SQL server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am just trying to Scaffold a DbContext using command in package console manager. I follow this tutorial for Db-first approach but I always getting "Build failed" error message.

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx

Below is the command I use:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=den1.mssql8.gear.host;Database=testdb;User Id=testdb;Password=actualPassword" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Unlike the tutorial, I was trying to use **remote SQL server** (sadly all the tutorial online use local sql server as if it is the only kind of db in the world)
I have ensured that I have installed the EntityFramework Provider for SQL server, along with the Tools from Nuget.

I have been digging for hours and can't find the answer for this, so any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the entire error message to the questions?

Comment: These type error are usually cause by two issues 1) Using wrong Instance name 2) Credentials.   First open SQL Server Management Studio and check the Server Name/Instance.  Make sure your connection string uses same as login.  Then check if the credentials is Windows.  If it is windows you do not need to use User Id and Password.  Instead use "Server=den1.mssql8.gear.host;Database=testdb; Integrated Security=true;"

Comment: @jdweng I tested my connection using SSMS (with SQL server authentication) and I can confirm that it can connect to the server.

Comment: Is you connection string using same credentials and Server/Instance as login window in SSMS?  Is database name the same as in the SSMS Explorer if you open the list of databases?  Windows credentials is the same as Integrated Security = true.  Also the Database testdb must be mounted on the server.

Comment: @jdweng yes, the database is the same "natedb". I don't use Window credential since it is a remote SQL server.
Ok... for whatever reason It just work when I re-run that command again.... I guess Bill Gates just descend to lend a hand in some ways. Thank you for your help still.

Comment: You are probably getting a timeout.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me after so many hours of unfruitful search

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=serverIpAddress;Database=testdb;User Id=testdb;Password=actualPassword" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
try it.

Answer (score 0):

For the VS22 M1 machine following command work for me

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=111.11.111.11;Database=MyDataBase;User Id=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

Comment: replace `Scaffold-DbContext` with `dbcontext scaffold`and `-OutputDir` with `-o` ... and add write `dotnet ef` in front of every command...